# how to connect to mdf file located in other directory (not in C:)

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

How can we connect to an sql server mdf file located in other directory not in "C". i.e the file is located in "E" drive. so what will be the connection string to connect with in C# Windows form. this is my connection string.

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=(local)\MSSQLSERVER;AttachDbFilename=E:\SaudiExchange.mdf;Database=SaudiExchange;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: That's handled server-side. You should be connecting to the instance (server\SQLEXPRESS) and specify the DB name in your connection string.

Comment: i added my connection string. just have a look at it. it's not working.

Comment: create a text file with extension .UDL and than doubleclick on it. You will now have a form where you can build your connectionstring and test it. If the connectionstring works than open the udl file with notepad and there you will have your connectionstring

Comment: @GuidoG it gives me the exception (Test Connection failed because of an error in initializing provider" unable to open the physical file "E:\SaudiExchange.mdf". Operating System error 5: "5(Access is denied)")

Comment: Sounds like a security issue. Does the user that opened the UDL file has read/write rights on E; ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `connection string` have to be like this :

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER;AttachDbFilename=E:\\SaudiExchange.mdf;Database=SaudiExchange;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and for local connection, you can try this one :

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.;Initial Catalog=SaudiExchange;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```